# Can we set Header in jsp and get it in servlet

Tags: jsp

I need your help in solving a problem. Actually i am creating a sample jsp page for my test purpose in which i want to send two input parameters(allowing user to enter) but that entered input i wanted to store as a header parameter. The reason for doing is, actually there is a third party who will hit out servlet and my servlet will get the header parameter from their end. As we dont have any setter method for HttpServeltRequest i was trying to do it using HttpResponse but still i am not clear how do my request.getHeader(headerName)) will retreive it. I am putting my effort here:'

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Try to be clearer

Comment: Why do you need to set the header on the request if the third party is apparently supposed to do this itself? This makes really no sense. What third party API are you talking about? Do they provide any documentation? Did you read and understand it?

Answer (score 1):

Since a standard html form has no support for header fields, you're best bet is doing this with AJAX. JQuery has good support for this, look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. The API allows you to specify headers when doing get/post operations.